# How run task in future in java at a particular date

Tags: java, oracle, timer, scheduled-tasks, futuretask

I have have to call a method in future so i found some example
Link are there 
[Link 1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)
[link 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html)

But I have to run it ONE TIME only.
at Date and Time  : 11-03-2014 10:15:20 (dd-MM-yyyy HH:MM:SS)

I how do it??

Answer (score 3):

The class [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) has exactly what you need:

First, set-up the task to be scheduled:

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

  void run() {
    //do the task
  }

};
```

Second, schedule the task:

```
Date futureDate = ...///whenever you want
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(task, futureDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Compute the delay between now and your target date, and call [`schedule()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) with this delay as argument:

```
Date targetDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(dateAsString);
long delayInMillis = targetDate - System.currentTimeMillis();
scheduler.schedule(task, delayInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: Done. But you really should be able to figure that out by yourself.

Comment: A task can't be shut down. Do you want to shut down the scheduler? You can do it from the task.